# Error when generate APK in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard

i want generate APK and use `ProGuard` for `obfuscate` my project.
but when generate APK, error for progurad.
i attached error picture in under link, please see it and help me :
Error image Link : [Image Link](http://s0.uploads.im/uNxcX.jpg)

Highlights different parts to my bookmarks

Comment: put -dontwarn com.caverock.** as package level and try once

Comment: did you call compile 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.2@aar' ?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya, yes yes. i use this lib. can you help me ?

Comment: Please comment out both line(from proguard-rules.pro) . And run this. say what happens ?